# Defer Css Loading lowers Page score on Mobile Phone Using Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-pagespeed, deferred-loading

I am Improving website score on Google Pagespeed Insights.

There was a recommendation to defer CSS load for (**Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content**)
So I tried  solution given on : [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)
As I did so, My desktop score improved but my mobile score dropped and for mobile it says :

"**Prioritize visible content
Your page requires additional network round trips to render the above-the-fold content. For best performance, reduce the amount of HTML needed to render above-the-fold content.**
The entire HTML response was not sufficient to render the above-the-fold content. This usually indicates that additional resources, loaded after HTML parsing, were required to render above-the-fold content. Prioritize visible content that is needed for rendering above-the-fold by including it directly in the HTML response.
**Only about 44% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response**"

Using the above solution my HTML would load without css and after a delay of around 1-2 sec the page would look better as css are now rendered by defer loading.

Is there any WAY to defer load a CSS for desktop and normal load them for Mobile ?